# why `card` element is not duplicated 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is `card` element not duplicated 4 times?

```js
function generate4Cards() {
  for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    var card = document.getElementById('card');
    document.body.appendChild(card);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="generate4Cards()">
  <div id="card">I am a card</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Because `appendChild` doesn't duplicate elements. It just attaches them to a specific place. If you want 4 of them, you need to clone them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `appendChild` with an existing element, that element will be *removed* from its former position in the DOM and appended to the new container. You'll have to explicitly create the `div` on each iteration instead.

But, having duplicate IDs in a single document is invalid HTML, so probably best to remove the `id` (or use a class instead):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var card = document.createElement('div');
  card.textContent = 'I am a card';
  document.body.appendChild(card);
}
```

Another option is to use `cloneNode`:

```js
var originalCard = document.querySelector('div');
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var card = originalCard.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(card);
}
```

```html
<div>I am a card</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo.append(bar)` puts `bar` at the end of `foo`.

If I put my car at the end of my road, and then put my car at the end of my drive then I don't have two cars.

`append` **only** puts `bar` where you tell it to put it.

It doesn't duplicate it because it isn't supposed to.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code you are looking for -

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function generate4Cards() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var card = document.createElement('div');
      card.textContent = 'I am a card';
      document.getElementById('cardHolder').appendChild(card);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="generate4Cards()>
<div id="cardHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though you actually need a CSS style to your card. :p